# Is there a way to make a concept that can represent a template parameter pack?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

With C++20, we can write a concept and use it like so:

```
template<typename T>
concept ClassType = std::is_class_v<T>;

template<ClassType T>
void foo();
```

Is there a way to achieve this same syntax when using template parameter packs? We could obviously do it with `requires`:

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
concept SameTypes = std::conjunction_v<std::is_same<T, Ts>...>;

template<typename... Ts>
requires SameTypes<Ts...>
void foo();
```

But my question is if there is way to do it using the syntax where the concept takes the place of `typename`, inside the template brackets like in the first example. Is there?

Comment: `template<ClassTypes... Ts>
void foo();` seems to works https://godbolt.org/z/7j5TfP7d7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, which is functional equivalence to your example:

```
#include <concepts>
template<class T, std::same_as<T>... Ts>
void foo();
```

Comment: well this is not what OP want though. (despite have same effect here)

Comment: @appleapple So what was the OP's intent?

Comment: Hm, this won't work if you need to perform SFINAE-stuff on the pack. For example checking if every type in the pack is the same. I have edited my post to use `std::is_same` instead to show what I mean

Comment: You don't handle empty pack though.

Comment: @Jarod42 Neither will the OP.

Comment: @JensB If your question doesn't ask what you want to ask, and someone has already answered your question, it is better to ask another question than edit and invalidate valid answers.  It isn't as if there is a fixed finite number of SO questions, adding another doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I see what you mean. Although, in this case I feel it might have been warranted because my question wasn't really *changed*, it was rather made a little more specific. The only thing I changed was the example used, so that it better showed what I wanted to do. And 康桓瑋's answer satisfied the question once he had seen the more specific example, and I accepted. So people coming across the question will still find the accepted answer matches the question